# Is there any function similar to _stprintf_s in Objective-C++?

Tags: macos, porting, objective-c++

I'm porting some lib from win32 platform to Mac OS. There're some functions using _stprintf_s to safely initialize strings.

Is there any function similar to _stprintf_s in Objective-C++?

Comment: I've found a function called snprintf. I don't know if they are the same or close?

Comment: In ObjC, I'd try [`NSString` formatting](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html) maybe? `NSStrings` are opaque and should be implemented with explicit bounds, so there's little risk of them pointing into random garbage memory.

Comment: Due to cross-platform needs, the base libs are codes in C++, it's better to use standard C++ methods.

Comment: I think `snprintf()` might be the standard equivalent to Windows' `sprintf_s()` (Of which `_stprintf_s()` seems to be the `tchar.h` equivalent. I don't think you should really be using `tchar.h` for anything anymore, it's not likely you need to support pre-Unicode versions of Windows.)

Comment: Then your question is misleading. You want to port the code you're asking about to standard C, not to Obj-C or Obj-C++ or standard C++. (Where you'd use `std::wstring` instead of C formatting functions.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found `swprintf` which works as a good substitution.

```
int swprintf(wchar_t *restrict ws, size_t n, const wchar_t *restrict format, ...);
```